# Enforce template type through static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, static-assert

I'm trying to understand the usefulness of `static_assert`, and I want to know if it can help me in enforcing a design, and if so, how.

I have a general template class that hides its own implementation inside another template class which is partially specialized based on the size of the template type. Here's a brief outline of this design:

```
template <class T, size_t S = sizeof(T)>
struct Helper;

template <class T>
struct Helper<T, sizeof(long)>
{
    static T bar();
};

// ... other specializations ...

template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:

    T bar()
    {
        return Helper<T>::bar();
    }
};
```

**Foo** is only supported if size of `T` is supported by a specialization of **Helper**. For example, `Foo<long>` and `Foo<unsigned long>` are both supported. However, suppose the user tries to construct a `Foo<bool>`. Normally, this would generate errors because the specialization of **Helper** for `bool` isn't defined, which is intended behaviour.

Is there any way to use `static_assert` in this design to provide more helpful errors to the user of this interface?

Additionally, I'd like to also restric the user from using a specific type, even though the size might be correct. For example, `Foo<float>` shouldn't be allowed. Right now, the only way I know of enforcing this is through a bold comment in the documentation. :)

Comment: Think more generally, is it just integer types that are supported? No `char`, `bool`, `float`, et al?

Comment: Search SO for template type constraints or "concepts".  A facility to do this was removed from C++11 at the last minute.  There are less automatic ways to achieve similar results though.

Comment: @Rapptz, `char`, `int`, and `long`, along with their `unsigned` versions should be supported. The code would be identical for `int`, `long`, and `unsigned long` if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == sizeof(unsigned long)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a better solution for this problem by combining the answers and comments here.

I can define a static type checker like so:

```
template <class A, class B>
struct CheckTypes
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class A>
struct CheckTypes<A, A>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Not sure if such a struct already exists in the standard library. Anyways, then in **Foo**, I can check for types and sizes using:

```
static_assert((sizeof(T) == sizeof(long) || sizeof(T) == sizeof(int)) && !CheckTypes<T, float>::value, "Error!");
```

Comment: it does, std::is_same

Comment: using sizeof isn't safe. it's just the size. long and int may be the same size, and a random structure that holds only an int will also have the same size.

Answer (score 31):

If it can only work for a specialization of the template class, then have the default template class raise a static assert:

```
template <class T, size_t S = sizeof(T)>
struct Helper
{
   static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1, "You have to have a specialization for Helper!" );
}
```

The default template class will only be chosen if there isn't a better specialization, therefore the assert will be risen.

You can use the same technique to disallow types, but you'll need another template parameter that will be used for the static assert check.

```
template <class T, class G = T, size_t S = sizeof(T)>
struct Helper
{
   static_assert(sizeof(G) == -1, "You have to have a specialization for Helper!" );
}

template <class G>
struct Helper<float,G>
{
   static_assert(sizeof(G) == -1, "You can't use float !" );
}

template <>
struct Helper<int>
{
 //This is a good specialization
};
```

Then you can try it with these variables:

```
Helper<bool> a;  //"You have to have a specialization for Helper!"
Helper<float> b; //"You can't use float !"
Helper<int> c;   //compiles OK
```

Comment: I believe you want `static_assert(false,...)`, so it always trips.  `static_assert` prints the error if the first argument is false.

Comment: This won't work as is - you need to make the assertion dependent (such as `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, ...);`), otherwise it gets processed at point of declaration, not instantiation.

Comment: @Angew have you checked? I'd expect it to fire at _shallow instantiation_ at first. N.m. I checked: you're right :)

Comment: I just tried this solution, and it doesn't work. It always raises an assertion whether or not the default specialization is used. Not sure if this behvaiour is dependant on the compiler.

Comment: @sehe Yup, I just did. It looks like checking the sizes is the way to go. You should include it as part of the answer. :)

Comment: Right, need to be instantiation dependent, otherwise the compiler will just run the assert anyway.

Comment: @sehe You're right. So i had to open visual studio for a better solution.

Comment: @Zeenobit I've changed the solution to work properly. Need to add another "invisible" template argument

Answer (score 12):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

`std::is_base_of` and `std::is_convertible` could help with your first issue and as for the second,

`static_assert(!std::is_same<float,T>(),"type can't be float");`

hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles upon this question, assuming OP probably found an answer in the 4 years since it was asked :)

Comment: I had to do `std::is_same<X, Y>::value` in VS2010 to avoid a C2057 expected constant expression error.